# Angular event undefined when listening to HTTPEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am facing a problem with listening to server response to Post request. I need to get progress rate, so I use Angular HttpEvent. I have a data-provider.service.ts, that sends post request to server:

```
postParams(targetDir, calParameter, saveCSV): Observable<any> {
const data = {
  targetDir: targetDir,
  calParameter: calParameter,
  saveCSV: saveCSV
};
return this.http
  .post<any>(this.SERVER_URL, data, {reportProgress: true})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('postParams')));
```

}

This method is called from app.component.ts:

```
  pathParams(folderPath: string, calParameter: number, saveCSV: string) {
  this.dataProvider.postParams(folderPath, calParameter, saveCSV).subscribe(event => {
    console.log(event.type);
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
              console.log('loading in progress');
    }
```

However I receive the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

What's wrong here?

Comment: What is x and  x.type?  Have you tried typeof(x)?

Comment: @sa_n__u I've edited code, because x was rather confusing. Anyway typeof(x) returned undefined.

Comment: Whats the result of `console.log(event);`

Comment: pass {reportProgress: true } check  [ https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events ]

Comment: @virendernehra But I pass it here: return this.http
  .post<any>(this.SERVER_URL, data, {reportProgress: true})

Comment: @sa_n__u undefined

Comment: @arti_lina not the result of console.log(event.type); I like to know the result of console.log(event);

Comment: @sa_n__u sorry, edited my reply, just 'undefined'

Comment: @arti_lina this.dataProvider() returning undefined value. first you have to find why it is returning undefined

Comment: @sa_n__u yeah, I get it, but why? Maybe reportProgress is not enough? The server  works fine, loading bar that is connected displays correct loading progress.

Comment: @arti_lina can u show me the frontend part of fetching data

Comment: @sa_n__u I'm confused, what do you mean? The data-provider.service.ts fetches data from http response from server.

Comment: @sa_n__u fixed it. {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'}

Comment: @arti_lina Okay nice.